# Trying to do hello world app for Nokia 5110 LCD with arduino yun and johnny five

Tags: lcd, arduino-yun, print, johnny-five

I have a Nokia 5110 LCD which is using this display `PCD8544`, I am using a arduino yun and johnny five I have hooked up the following pins. So far with my node app all that happens is the lcd lights up. I am not sure if maybe the lcd is not supported with johnny five, if I have a pin wrong. I followed this site for the pin setup https://lastminuteengineers.com/nokia-5110-lcd-arduino-tutorial/ Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first attempt with Johnny five and second attempt at hooking anything up to a bread board. Hope we can get this working. Thanks

Here is my code

```
const five = require('johnny-five');
const board = new five.Board();


board.on("ready", function() {

    lcd = new five.LCD({
      controller: "PCF8574"
    });

    lcd.print("Hello");
  });
```

Here is my configuration

```
blue         =  pin 7          sclk     (serial clock(CLK)) 10 om
white        =  pin 6          DN(MOSI) (Serial data in) 10om
grey         =  pin 5          D/C      (Mode select) 10om
orange       =  pin 4          RST      (Reset) 10om
yellow/red   =  pin 3          SCE      (Chip select) 10om
yellow-short =  power strip +  LED      (backlight supply) 1kom
green/black  =  gnd / strip - 
blue/power   =  3.4v power + 330om
```

Here is are some images of the setup

[image: arduino setup #1]

[image: arduino setup #2]

[image: arduino setup #3]

Update so my configuration looks more like this now

```
blue         =  pin 7          sclk     (serial clock(CLK)) 10k
white        =  pin 6          DN(MOSI) (Serial data in) 10k
grey         =  pin 5          D/C      (Mode select) 10k
orange       =  pin 4          RST      (Reset) 10k
yellow/red   =  pin 3          SCE      (Chip select) direct
yellow-short =  power strip +  LED      (backlight supply) 330
green/black  =  gnd / strip - 
blue/power   =  3.4v power powerstrip direct
```

Comment: does the code compile without errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors, I can console log the board, and the repl just starts with johnny five

Comment: Follow the instructions on your page: use 10k (not 10 ohms) on the signal lines. Get rid of the 330-ohm connected to the display's VCC, there should no resistance there at all. Use that 330-ohm for the BL pin instead.

Comment: that's a mistake on my part I was using 10k, but the 330 I guess was in the wrong spot, so I moved it to the backlight pin, now It doesn't light up. Have to figure this out now.

Comment: I added my new config above still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino Yun is a ATMega32U4-based board, like other ATMega32U4-based Arduino boards, such as Arduino Leonardo, Micro, the SPI is only available on the ICSP header:

```
MOSI - Yun has it on ICSP Pin 4
MISO - Yun has it on ICSP Pin 1
SCK - Yun has it on ICSP pin 3
SS - Yun has no dedicated pin, use any digital data pin
```

You can find out the ICSP header pin assignment at [Arduino SPI](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI) reference page. So here is the connection between Arduino Yun and LCD5110

```
Yun               LCD 5110
ICSP pin3         CLK(SCK)
ICSP pin 4        DN(MOSI)
any GPIO pin      D/C (see note 1)
RST               RST
any GPIO pin      SCE(SS) (see note 1)
any GPIO pin      Backlight (via a 330 ohm resistor) (see note 2)
GND               GND
3v3               VCC
```

> Note 1: Although you could use any GPIO for D/C and SCE, you should consult the library that you are using to see what pin the library used for the data/command line and SS line.
>
> Note 2: Connecting to a GPIO pin allows you to turn on and off the LED backlight, you could ignore the connection if you don't want the backlight, or you could connect it directly to 3v3 via a resistor if you want backlight on permanently

If you still have problem in using the LCD5110, please update your question with complete code and the library that you are using.

Comment: Im still working on this, I tried the new arrangment and still no led, or any text to screen. When you say library are you refering to this http://johnny-five.io/api/lcd/ that's the API I am using. The only other thing I can think of is I am using Firmata to connect Johnny Five To the Board. I'll look over my config again and see if I am missing something, but still quite stuck.

Comment: I took a look at the library that you are using, I don't think it supports SPI to begin with. The Nokia 5110 is a display with SPI interface and the library seems to be a wrong one.

Comment: Oh ok well I will just try and get some leds going, I just wanted to get that libary working period. Down the road want to do some soil testing. Ok I'll select your answer thanks for all the help

Comment: Maybe update your answer saying I am using the wrong library, in case someone else needs to know

Comment: You can easily find Arduino LCD library for LCD5110 if you are using c++(i.e. Arduino), I wrote my own [library](https://github.com/e-tinkers/LCD-5110-Arduino-library) a few years ago as part of my learning. Maybe you could port it JS.